Issue with Drag and Drop of widgets
.grid {
  --gap: 1em;
  --columns: 2;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: column;
  columns: var(--columns);
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.grid>* {
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: var(--gap);
}

@supports (grid-template-rows: masonry) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: masonry;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
  }

  .grid>* {
    margin-bottom: 0em;
  }
}

.featured {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

:root {
  --ff-primary: basic-sans, sans-serif;
  --clr-primary: #ee6352;
  --clr-body: #333;
  --clr-bg: #ddd;
  --spacer: 1rem;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.drag-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3rem;
  top: 0.8rem;
  cursor: move;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let box of boxes; let i = index">
      <div class="box" [ngClass]="'box-' + (i + 1)" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event, i)">
        <button class="drag-button" draggable="true" (dragstart)="onDragStart($event, i)" (dragend)="onDragEnd()">
          <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/521614/drag.svg" width="24" />
        </button>
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="box.component"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>


import { Component, Renderer2, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ExistingHoldingWidgetComponent } from './existing-holding-widget/existing-holding-widget.component';
import { GoalBuilderWidgetComponent } from './goal-builder-widget/goal-builder-widget.component';
import { HistoricalAssessmentWidgetComponent } from './historical-assessment-widget/historical-assessment-widget.component';
import { TipsAndTricksWidgetComponent } from './tips-and-tricks-widget/tips-and-tricks-widget.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  boxes = [
    { id: 1, component: HistoricalAssessmentWidgetComponent},
    { id: 2, component: ExistingHoldingWidgetComponent},
    { id: 3, component: GoalBuilderWidgetComponent},
    { id: 4, component: TipsAndTricksWidgetComponent}
  ];

  draggedBoxIndex: number | null = null;
  private globalClickListener: () => void;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.globalClickListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (event: Event) => {

    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.globalClickListener) {
      this.globalClickListener();
    }
  }

  onDragStart(event: DragEvent, index: number) {
    this.draggedBoxIndex = index;
    event.dataTransfer?.setData('text', index.toString());
    event.dataTransfer!.effectAllowed = 'move';

    const originalBox = document.querySelector(`.box-${index + 1}`) as HTMLElement;
    const clonedBox = originalBox.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement;

    clonedBox.style.position = 'absolute';
    clonedBox.style.top = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(clonedBox);

    event.dataTransfer?.setDragImage(clonedBox, 0, 0);

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.removeChild(clonedBox);
    }, 0);
  }

  onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer!.dropEffect = 'move';
  }

  onDrop(event: DragEvent, index: number) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const draggedIndex = parseInt(event.dataTransfer?.getData('text') || '0', 10);

    if (draggedIndex !== index) {
      [this.boxes[draggedIndex], this.boxes[index]] = [this.boxes[index], this.boxes[draggedIndex]];
    }
    this.draggedBoxIndex = null;
  }

  onDragEnd() {
    this.draggedBoxIndex = null;
  }
}


.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
    color: #333;
}

.p-1 {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 0.8rem 0.8rem 0.5rem;
}

.menu-button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 45px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown li {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    color: #555;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

<div class="header">
  <h3>
    Existing Holding
  </h3>
  <button class="menu-button" (click)="toggleDropdown($event)">
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/422519/dot-menu-more.svg" width="24" />
    <div *ngIf="isDropdownOpen" class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems" (click)="handleDropdownAction(item)">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </button>

   </div>

<div class="p-1">
      Content for Existing Holding.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tiLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tiLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh tincidunt imperdiet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat felis at nibh ti
</div>
  


import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DropdownComponent } from '../drop-down/dropdown.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-existing-holding-widget',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, DropdownComponent],
  templateUrl: './existing-holding-widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./existing-holding-widget.component.css']
})
export class ExistingHoldingWidgetComponent {

  isDropdownOpen = false;
  dropdownItems = ['Collapse 1', 'Option 2', 'Collapse 3'];

  private globalClickListener: () => void;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.globalClickListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (event: Event) => {
      this.closeDropdowns(event);
    });
  }

  toggleDropdown(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    this.isDropdownOpen = !this.isDropdownOpen;
  }

  handleDropdownAction(action: string) {
    this.isDropdownOpen = false;
  }

  closeDropdowns(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const clickedInside = target.closest('.menu-button');

    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.isDropdownOpen = false;
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.globalClickListener) {
      this.globalClickListener(); // Remove global listener
    }
  }
}


According to Angular CDK Drag Drop Documentation, all the droppable items should be written with an *ngFor directive iterating through an array. But what if the items that I want to make droppable are angular components? What is the procedure to make them droppable?
For example, the following code is to render a normal droppable div. What if I want to render multiple angular components on the 2nd line. In that case, I can't use the *ngFor directive because every angular components are very different and I can't keep them in any array.
